# Member Access in Java

Tags: java

I have code where a variable name is identical to the class name. I.e.:

```
class Foo {
  static public void main(String[] args) {
    Integer Foo;
    Foo.main(args);
  }
}
```

How can I call the main-method without renaming the variable or the class?

Comment: Why do you need to call it like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's not in the default package you could refer to it via the package name also, e.g.:

```
packagename.Foo.main(args);
```

or you can simply refer to main without the class name, e.g.:

```
main(args);
```

Comment: C++ has the keyword "::" to give access to class members. Is there such a keyword in Java?

Comment: not that I'm aware of. I assume this is one of the reasons using the default package is discouraged.

Comment: So the packages, classes and variables should/must have always different names in java because java doesn't disambiguate between classes and variables when using "."?

Comment: @fre The names do not _have_ to be different; they occupy different name spaces. There can be bad source-level ambiguities when class names collide with variables (as you have discovered). This also happens when class names collide with (sub)package names. (Is `mypackage.Foo.main` the name of class `main` in package `mypackage.Foo`, the name of a method, variable, or inner class in class `mypackage.Foo`?) Once the compiler knows what the symbol references, though, it can compile it into running byte codes even if the names are the same. Obfuscators love to take advantage of this.

Answer (score 3):

If class `Foo` is in a package, you could use the fully qualified name:

```
my.package.Foo.main(args);
```

You could also rename variable `Foo`; it's bad Java style to capitalize variable names. Finally, why would you want to call `main` from `main` like that? It's going to overflow the stack very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Integer` does not have a `main(...)` method, this is not a problem.
More generally speaking, if you need to disambiguate, use the full package name.

Answer (score 0):

use the full package name, it works.

```
package my.pck;
class Foo {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        Integer Foo;
        my.pck.Foo.main(new String[] { "arg" });
    }
}
```

But  why would you want to call main from main like that? its creating infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I have code where a variable name is identical to the class name

Why? The simple answer is "don't". The convention is that class names start with a capital and member variable names don't, which takes care of it completely.